# Is there any way to execute step by step a Windows Workflow Foundation using C#?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am a beginner with Windows Workflow Foundation, I'm trying to execute the next sequential flow

```
new Sequence()
{              
    Activities = {
        new WriteLine() { Text = "Step 1" },
        new WriteLine() { Text = "Step 2" },
        new WriteLine() { Text = "Step 3" },
        new WriteLine() { Text = "Step 4" },
    }
};
```

When I do

```
WorkflowApplication application = new WorkflowApplication(activity);
application.Run();
```

the flow runs each step according to planned

I'd like to know if is there any way to execute this flow step by step, I mean, something like:

```
application.Next(); //expected output "Step 1"
application.Next(); //expected output "Step 2"
application.Next(); //expected output "Step 3"
application.Next(); //expected output "Step 4"
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `activity`? `Sequence` is collection of activities, which in turn contain delegate. I am not into WFF, but something like `sequence.Activities[0].Implementation()` will execute the first delegate. Or maybe [more officially](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/using-workflowinvoker-and-workflowapplication): `WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(sequence.Activities[0])`.

Comment: activitiy = new Sequence(); Thanks for reply

Comment: Take the [tour], read [ask], and [mcve]. `new Sequence {...}` is not valid C# code. [Edit] your post to include the full type declaration of `activity`.